# Как изменить размеры сопоставленных (mapped) разделов в линуксе?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система

Ввожу в командной строке: **df -h**, вижу:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         772M  9.1M  763M   2% /run
/dev/sda1                     4.7G  3.0G  1.5G  67% /
tmpfs                         3.8G   79M  3.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--common  2.0G  3.1M  1.8G   1% /opt/some-common
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--game     12G  1.5G   11G  13% /opt/some
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--var      20G   45M   19G   1% /opt/some-var
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--log      20G   48M   19G   1% /opt/some-log
tmpfs                         772M     0  772M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Меня интересуют разделы, начинающиейся на **/dev/mapper**

Какой инструмент скорее всего так примонтовал эти разделы и как изменить (сократить) их?
(GParted их не видит)

---

Сделал **lvm> lvreduce --size 5G /dev/mapper/some-gkt--log** , но, к сожалению, полетела файловая система (после перезагрузки пишет: **“Welcome to emergency mode!”**). Не хотелось бы (и нет времени) изучать все заклинания этой магии, не могли бы вы привести непосредственную последовательно действий для сокращения раздела **/dev/mapper/vg01-some--log** до заданного размера

---

Что-то мне недостает в знаниях. Сократил логическую партицию - сломалась файловая система (**“Welcome to emergency mode!”**), потом обратно увеличил до прежнего размера и опять все починилось. Что-то еще нужно сделать после **lvreduce**, но что??

Comment: Примонтировала ОС. :) Это Logical Volume. Почитайте, [как взаимодействовать](http://xgu.ru/wiki/LVM) с LVM.

Comment: например: http://jnotes.ru/change-size-ext4-lvm.html

Comment: Сделал **lvm> lvreduce --size 5G /dev/mapper/some-gkt--log** но к сожалению полетела файловая система. Не хотелось бы (и нет времени) изучать все заклинания этой магии, не могли бы вы привести непосредственную последовательно действий

Comment: @asianirish, по приведённой мною ссылке всё написано более чем конкретно. без единого магического заклинания: сначала уменьшить размер файловой системы, а уж потом — блочного устройства. если не уменьшить предварительно размер файловой системы, то она «испортится».

Comment: @alexander barakin да, спасибо, разобрался, смутило вступление автора статьи "произвожу шаманство" :). Комментарий тянет на ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

логический том (*logical volume*, *lv*) в *lvm* (*logical volume management*) — это примерный «аналог» либо всего блочного устройства («диска», «винчестера», «hdd»), если оно не разбито на разделы, либо раздела на блочном устройстве (с функциональной точки зрения раздел блочного устройства также является блочным устройством).

так же, как и на любом блочном устройстве, на *lv* можно создать файловую систему («отформатировать»).

обычно файловая система занимает всё пространство блочного устройства, но, в общем, ничто (кроме искусственных ограничений или недоделок в реализации кода, работающего с данной ф.с.) не мешает ей занимать лишь **часть** блочного устройства.

из приведённых соображений, надеюсь, становится понятно, что если требуется уменьшить размер блочного устройства («диска», его раздела, логического тома *lvm* и т.п.), предварительно надо уменьшить размер файловой системы. иначе «она испортится» (© мудрый медведь пух).

---

скорее всего, у вас на всех *lv* используются файловые системы семейства [*ext**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext) (уточнить можно, например, с помощью `df -T`, если ф.с. смонтирована, либо, например, с помощью `sudo blkid`, если нет; см., например, [этот](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53552/110559) ответ). из этого и будем исходить.

для уменьшения размера ф.с. надо:

1. отмонтировать её, если была смонтирована:

   ```
   $ sudo umount блочное-устройство-или-точка-монтирования
   ```

   если файлы из этой ф.с. используются, отмонтировать не удастся. в таком случае имеет смысл воспользваться каким-нибудь live/rescue-носителем, загрузившись с него.
2. проверить её целостность:

   ```
   $ sudo e2fsck -f блочное-устройство
   ```

   (кстати, без этого шага программа *resize2fs* просто откажется работать, выдав соответствующее напоминание).
3. уменьшить размер файловой системы. либо до указанного размера (размер можно указывать в блоках, либо, добавив суффикс, в соответствующих единицах измерения, например, `100G` — сто гигабайт; см. `man resize2fs`):

   ```
   $ sudo resize2fs блочное-устройство размер
   ```

   либо «до предела»:

   ```
   $ sudo resize2fs -M блочное-устройство
   ```

   второй вариант (с моей точки зрения) предпочтительнее, так как на самом деле файловая система должна занимать **чуть меньше** места, чем размер блочного устройство — из-за всяких там выравниваний, мета-информации и т.п., и, если указать одинаковый размер и при уменьшении ф.с., и при последующем уменьшении блочного устройства, ф.с. в результате может «чуть-чуть» не уместиться, а следовательно, придётся «чуть-чуть» увеличивать размер блочного устройства, чтобы её «починить».

а теперь можно уменьшать и размер блочного устройства — *lv*:

```
$ sudo lvreduce -L размер блочное-устройство
```

если на предыдущем шаге вы выбрали вариант «уменьшить ф.с. до указанного размера», то в данный момент настоятельно рекомендуется проверить целостность ф.с. (см. выше), и, если проверка будет неудачной, надо будет по «чуть-чуть» увеличивать размер блочного-устройства (`шаг` имеет смысл указывать где-то в районе мегабайта — `-L +1m`, при необходимости можно повторить):

```
$ sudo lvresize -L +шаг блочное-устройство
```

если же на предыдущем шаге вы уменьшили размер ф.с. «до предела», то теперь надо сделать обратную операцию — увеличить этот размер «до предела», чтобы ф.с. заняла всё свободное пространство блочного устройства:

```
$ sudo resize2fs блочное-устройство
```